# I'm making a program to simulate a game of war, but I keep getting an error at random times while it's trying to get a random card

Tags: java

Here is the code that I'm working on, and I have the crashy area marked (line 48). Everything else works as intended, but I can't seem to figure out how to prevent the error. It obviously wants to pull a card, but the card doesn't exist for some reason, even though the deck size minuser comes before.

```
import java.util.*;
public class cardDeck
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  ArrayList<Integer> deck=loadDeck();
  System.out.println(deck);
  Collections.sort(deck);
  System.out.println(deck);
  System.out.println();
  war(deck);
 }
 static ArrayList<Integer> loadDeck()
 {
  ArrayList<Integer> deck=new ArrayList<Integer>();
  int j=0;
  while(j<4)
  {
   int i=2;
   while(i<=14)
   {
    deck.add(i);
    i++;
   }
   j++;
  }
  return deck;
 }
 static void war(ArrayList <Integer> deck)
 {
  int round=1;
  int deckSize=52;
  int p1score=0;
  int p2score=0;
  int ties=0;
  while(round<=26)
  {
   System.out.println("Round Number: "+round);
   System.out.println("-----------------------");
   int index1=(int)(Math.random()*deckSize);
   int index2=(int)(Math.random()*deckSize);
   int card1=deck.get(index1);
   int card2=deck.get(index2);
   System.out.println("Player1 drew: "+card1);
   deck.remove(deck.get(index1));
   deckSize--;
   System.out.println("Player2 drew: "+card2);
   deck.remove(deck.get(index2));                   //crashes here at random times
   deckSize--;
   System.out.println();
   if(card1>card2)
   {
    System.out.println("Player1 wins this round");
    p1score+=2;
    p1score+=ties*2;
    ties=0;
    System.out.println("Player1 score: "+p1score);
    System.out.println("Player2 score: "+p2score);
    System.out.println();
   }
   else if(card1<card2)
   {
    System.out.println("Player2 wins this round");
    p2score+=2;
    p2score+=ties*2;
    ties=0;
    System.out.println("Player1 score: "+p1score);
    System.out.println("Player2 score: "+p2score);
    System.out.println();
   }
   else
   {
    System.out.println("Neither wins this round");
    ties++;
    System.out.println("Ties: "+ties);
    System.out.println();
   }
   round++;
  }
 }
}
```

Exception, although it varies, since the area it crashes at varies.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:458)
    at cardDeck.war(cardDeck.java:48)
    at cardDeck.main(cardDeck.java:11)
```

Comment: Would you please paste the full stack trace of the exception you received into the question?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I think this is because you decide on index2 before you decrement decksize. If index2 refers to the last card in the deck, the the get will cause an IndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: Once I read your comment, that totally made sense and I can't believe I overlooked it, Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful and considerate to other members of SO if this question were marked solved. Whether @NomadMaker puts their answer (why put an answer in the comments? why not put it in the answer area? this comments section is for asking for clarifications) in for selection or the OP records the solution there and marks it, either works.

Comment: @Phil Freihofner: I'm not NomadMaker, but the reason I answer in the comments is that the answer is simple and generally only helpful to the OP and no one else.  There are dozens (maybe hundreds) of IndexOutOfBounds questions, some of which have answers.  In other words, this is a duplicate question.  The OP is too new to Java to have any idea how to search for common problems he'll encounter.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I see your reasoning, but it assumes the OP will then erase the question? We get a lot of clutter this way. Unanswered questions draw views from people with a generous desire to be helpful, but it wastes their time, reading a question not knowing it's already been answered is my point. It may feel modest/unobtrusive, but it has a cost on other people's time.